# Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen einem "Sprichwort", einer "Redewendung" und einer "Redensart"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen einem Sprichwort, einer Redewendung und einer Redensart, oder sind diese Begriffe synonym?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ein **Sprichwort** ist laut Wolfgang Mieder, [zitiert nach  Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprichwort), ein "allgemein bekannter, fest geprägter Satz, der eine Lebensregel oder Weisheit in prägnanter, kurzer Form ausdrückt“. Beispiel:

> Wer den Pfennig nicht ehrt, ist des Talers nicht wert.

Die Unterscheidung zwischen [Redensarten](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redensart) und [Redewendungen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redewendung) scheint etwas unklar zu sein, wenn man sich ihre Wikipedia-Artikel anschaut. Beide sind per Interwiki-Links mit Artikeln mit dem Titel "Idiom" verlinkt, was die Vermutung unterstützt, dass beide synonym seien. Laut dem ["Redensart"-Artikel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redensart) sind Redewendungen in ihrer Satzanordnung festgelegt, Redensarten nicht. Laut dem ["Redewendung"-Artikel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redewendung) sind Redensarten "sprichwörtlich" -- ich verstehe da "metaphorisch":

> Schwein haben (= Glück haben)

... während Redewendungen auch im Wortsinne verwendet werden können:

> Der Ofen ist aus (= wörtlich bzw. "Das vorher Genannte ist zu Ende")

Auf jeden Fall gibt es eine deutliche Unterscheidung zwischen diesen beiden einerseits und Sprichwörtern andererseits: **Sprichwörter** sind Sätze und **Aussagen** -- "Die Welt ist so." --, **Redewendungen** und **Redensarten** sind **Ausdrücke**, die sich als Bestandteile von Sätzen auf unterschiedliche Dinge beziehen können.

Comment: Wunderbar - das paßt wie Faust auf's Auge! Nur - wie merke ich mir ''Aussage vs. Ausdruck'' ... :)

Comment: @userunknown Die Aus_sage_ kann ihren Wortlaut verändern, behält dabei aber den Sinn bei. "Stille Post" trifft es nicht ganz, hilft aber vielleicht als Eselsbrücke. Der Aus_druck_ zeichnet sich dadurch aus, dass er bestimmte Wörter enthält. (Und, einmal gedruckt, verändern sich die Wörter nicht mehr.)